# Api integration of open-Km is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present Origin 'URL' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: java, angular, wildfly, openkm

I have a problem integrating an openkmapi with angular application, I'm more on the sysops of knowledge so need some help.

When I use the url of open-km with the we app it gives me an error related to cors origin, I tried to search what to do but I'm not sure if the problem is with the angular webapp (on Wildfly) or with the open-km (docker container).

Any idea on how to solve such an issue or where should the solution be, cause I'm not sure on which side the issue is.